# make a post request with in node.js application

Tags: node.js, microservices

I've a node.js service with /api/authenticate endpoint. I can call this service successfully from POSTMAN with 'username' and 'password' as input (body parameters). How do I call the same services from another node.js server?

With postman I get,

```
body: {name: 'xxxxxx', password: 'xxxxxx' }
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '0' }
```

## POST /api/authenticate 200 1.336 ms - 72

Following is another nodejs application ... which makes a successful request call but doesn't have any body parameters (username and password) when it reaches to the authentication server api.

```
var my_http = require('http');

app.get('/makeacall', function(req, res) {
  var output = '';
  var options = {
    body: { name: 'xxxxxx', password: 'xxxxxx' },
    method: 'POST',
    host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
    port: 'xxxx',
    path: '/api/authenticate',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

console.log('before request');

var req = my_http.request(options, function(response) {
  console.log('response is: ' + response);
  console.log('Response status code: ' + response.statusCode); 
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
   console.log('Data ..');
   output += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function(chunk) {
   console.log('Whole Data ..' + output);
  });

});
req.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + err);
});
req.end();
console.log('444');
res.send({ message: 'View record message'});
```

});

From this nodejs application I get empty body on the server.

```
body: {}
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-length': '0' }
POST /api/authenticate 200 1.336 ms - 72
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stock http library of NodeJS doesn't allow you to use that syntax.

Take a look at [RequestJS](https://github.com/request/request) as a much simpler solution. It will make your life a lot easier and allow you to use the syntax you want.

This is the solution to do it with stock Node.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Relevant Parts:

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});
```

And then, at the end:

```
// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

But use a library unless you absolutely can't.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the posted data from a form/etc?

Try using express.

`npm install express -save`

You can get posted data from a url with the ff:

```
app.post('*', function(request, response){  
    var post = {};
    if(Object.keys(request.body).length){
        for(var key in request.body){
            post[key] = request.body[key];
            console.log(key+'=>'+post[key];
        }
    }
});
```